# A-FRAME: How to show SVG animation

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

Is it possible to insert animated svg element into a-frame canvas or render it as shader texture onto a primitive mesh?

I've tried using the [aframe-htmlembed-component](https://github.com/supereggbert/aframe-htmlembed-component) but it renders svg just as a still image.

Also, i've tried the [aframe-gif-shader](https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-shader) which worked just fine, I'd only need this for svg animations.

Comment: Hello - I am using the aframe-htmlembed-component and cannot get SVG to render at all. Could you share your code with me to embed SVG? Thanks my test on CodePen https://codepen.io/luketobrien/pen/pXJydb